# ¿Cómo rellenar un array con valores null?

Tags: php, array, laravel-5, null

Les cuento, estoy usando un formulario que me muestra todos los valores de un array (llamados documentos) en forma de checkbox. Al momento de rescatar los valores de los array este me muestra solo los valores seleccionados (su valor es la id de documentos) y necesito que me muestre todos, incluso los que no están seleccionados:

```
  array:4 [▼
  0 => "4"
  1 => "14"
  2 => "35"
  3 => "15"
]
```

de esta manera se me muestra y son 19 documentos, necesito que se me muestren todos y en caso de que no tengan valor se les asigne uno nulo:

algo asi:

```
array:19 [▼
  0 => null
  1 => "4"
  2 => null
  3 => "14"
  4 => null
  5 => null
  6 => null
  7 => null
  8 => null
  9 => "35"
  10 => null
  11 => null
  12 => null
  13 => null
  14 => null
  15 => null
  16 => "15"
  17 => null
  18 => null
]
```

De antemano les agradezco por haber leido y por su colaboración:)!

---

ACTUALIZO:

la interfaz donde se presentan los check es la siguiente:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {!! Form::label('documentos', 'Documentos') !!}
        @foreach ($documentos as $documento)
            <div class="checkbox" onchange="javascript:mostrarOcultar()">
                <label>
                    {!! Form::checkbox('documento[]', $documento->id, null, 
                        ['class' => 'field check']) !!}
                    {{ $documento->nombre }} 
                </label>
                <label> 
                    {!! Form::text('details[]', null, 
                        ['class' => 'form-control detalle',
                        'style' => 'display: block;', 
                        'placeholder' => 'Detalles',
                        'for' => $documento->id,
                        'title' => 'OPCIONAL : Ingrese una especificación del documento.'])
                    !!}
                </label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

y los llamo con el siguiente código:

```
$documento = $request->get('documento');
    $detalle = $request->get('details');
```

como pueden ver, los "details" me muestran todos los valores pero por alguna razón, los documentos me muestra solos los que marque.

Comment: hola, se refiere a lo que publiqué?

Comment: si, ahora está perfecto :)

Comment: jejej alguna sugerencia amigo, de como poder resolverlo?

Comment: supongo que con un `foreach()` lo puedes hacer, verificas si el valor es vacío (`" "`) y lo cambias a `null`

Comment: si asi lo intenté, pero no puedo rescatar todos los valores y solo me permite manipular los que han sido seleccionados:(

Comment: bueno no soy experto en php ni en temas de web, dejemos que alguien que realmente sepa responda tu pregunta :D

Comment: de todos modos muchas gracias!

Comment: Si agregas el código sería mas sencillo ayudarte. Solo pusiste el array lo cuál no es muy ilustrativo.

Comment: bien, lo pondré

Comment: Y podrías crear un campo hidden que tenga la cantidad de elementos del checkbox, luego tienes los marcados, la diferencia serían los elementos no seleccionados.

Comment: javier Snachez: hola, disculpe amigo, no le entendí

Comment: si, por ejemplo, si tenés un check con 18 elementos, podés enviar esa cantidad en un campo input de tipo hidden, y en el servidor tomás ese valor, y si en $request->get('documento') tenés 4 valores, quiere decir que los restantes 14 son nulos.

Comment: aah... buena, lo intentaré, gracias por su ayuda:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar asignar el índice directamente a cada elemento:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {!! Form::label('documentos', 'Documentos') !!}
        @foreach ($documentos as $documento)
            <div class="checkbox" onchange="javascript:mostrarOcultar()">
                <label>
                    {!! Form::checkbox("documento[{$documento->id}]", $documento->id, null, 
                        ['class' => 'field check']) !!}
                    {{ $documento->nombre }} 
                </label>
                <label> 
                    {!! Form::text("details[{$documento->id}]", null, 
                        ['class' => 'form-control detalle',
                        'style' => 'display: block;', 
                        'placeholder' => 'Detalles',
                        'for' => $documento->id,
                        'title' => 'OPCIONAL : Ingrese una especificación del documento.'])
                    !!}
                </label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

De esta forma, deberías recibir un arreglo `documento` como este, donde el índice no es secuencial, sino el número de documento (igual al valor):

```
array:4 [
    4 => "4"
    14 => "14"
    35 => "35"
    15 => "15"
]
```

Ahora puedes recorrer `details` para saber si se marcó el checkbox y hacer las tareas necesarias directamente:

```
$documento = $request->get('documento');
$detalle = $request->get('details');
// El índice no es secuencial, sino el número de documento:
foreach($detalle as $index => $valor) {
    // Buscar checkbox
    if(isset($documento[$index])) {
        // El checkbox para este documento fue marcado;
        // Usar directamente sin más rodeos
    }
}
```

Solo si necesitas tener ambos arreglos con el mismo orden para comparaciones posteriores, la opción sería:

```
// Crear un arreglo con los checkboxes marcados
$checkboxes = $request->get('documento');
$detalle = $request->get('details');
// Crear un nuevo arreglo para documentos, con el mismo orden de $detalle
$documento = [];
// El índice no es secuencial, sino el número de documento:
foreach($detalle as $index => $valor) {
    // Buscar checkbox
    if(isset($checkboxes[$index])) {
        // El checkbox para este documento fue marcado
        $documento[$index] = $index;
    } else {
        // El checkbox no fue marcado, agregas null al arreglo
        $documento[$index] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: muchisimas, muchisimas gracias!!! que esté muy bien!!!